# How can I add UV Sphere to Stickman to later add Armature?

Tags: modifiers, armature, bones, vertices

This is tough one for me... Althrough I have been using Blender only for a week, about 80% of that was wasted on trying to do what I described in question title.

I have made small stickman with **low** amount of vertices. Basically it has 2 calves, 2 thighs, 2 forearms and 2 arms + 1 body == 9 vertices (and 9 bones).

It's easy to add armature at this point, but my problem is, I want head that looks like a ball. 100% rounded.

UV Sphere with "smooth vertex" does the job.

But here I encounter a problem: I cant add it to my stickman. I use SKIN modifier (which I later use to add Armature, it has button for it) on my stickman

This seems to add vertices or something similar to vertices. But anyway - it lags my blender if I have joined Head (Uv Sphere) to body (stickman) simply because of the amount of vertices that UV sphere has.

So I did something like that as workaround:

1. created normal stickman without head.
2. added skin modifier and armature.
3. pressed apply on skin modifier.
4. added head(uv sphere) and joined (ctrl + j) head with body.

But then, my armature wasnt connected to the head. If I moved body, it would move without head, regardless of head being before joined to body with ctrl+J. How can I achieve it?

How could I achieve what I need?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution will be to keep the head separate of the body, place the "ball" in place. Change armature mode to Pose, select the ball, Shift select the armature. It'll be in pose mode, so you will be able to select single bone. Select "head" bone and press CTRL+P - Set Parent to - Bone.

Comment: you saved me, thanks a lot. i gave u +1 and clicked that curved stick below. have a good day!